# Pass Type as a parameter to template function

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, templates

I am refactoring my code and I want to replace these calls:

```
            OnClickEv onClickPr = GetScriptPr<OnClickEv>(controlProps);
            if (onClickPr != null && onClickPr.Value != null)
                _script.Add(onClickPr.Value.ToString());

            OnDblClickEv onDblClickPr = GetScriptPr<OnDblClickEv>(controlProps);
            if (onDblClickPr != null && onDblClickPr.Value != null)
                _script.Add(onDblClickPr.Value.ToString());

            OnKeyDownEv onKeyDownEv = GetScriptPr<OnKeyDownEv>(controlProps);
            if (onKeyDownEv != null && onKeyDownEv.Value != null)
                _script.Add(onKeyDownEv.Value.ToString());
```

with single function where I simply pass classes or Types that should be processed:

```
CreateSimplePropWithParam(controlProps, new List<Type>()
            {
                typeof(OnClivkEv), typeof(OnDblClickEv), typeof(OnKeyDownEv)
            });
```

Template function:

```
private T GetScriptPr<T>(List<ScriptPr> properties) where T : ScriptPr
        {
            var pr = properties.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault();

            return (T)pr;
        }
```

**But how to pass that Type parameter to Template?**

```
private void CreateSimplePropWithParam(List<ScriptPr> controlProps, DesignerPlatform designerPlatform, object param, List<Type> propsList)
        {
            foreach (Type type in propsList)
            {
                T prop = (ScriptPr)GetScriptPr<T>(controlProps); <<< what to do with T?


                if (prop != null && prop.Value != null)
                {...
}}}
```

Comment: C# has no templates like in C++. C# has generics allowing strong-typing. Templates are the ancestors of generics. The usage of `T` comes from the word Template, so it is understandable that this causes confusion. [Differences Between C++ Templates and C# Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics)

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to use reflection; in particular, you want `MakeGenericMethod`, i.e.

```cs
static readonly MethodInfo s_GetScriptPr = typeof(Whatever)
    .GetMethod("GetScriptPr", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
...
object result = s_GetScriptPr.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(targetInstance,
    new object[] { controlProps });
```

Note: generics and reflection aren't easy to use together correctly, and if you *can* avoid it, you usually should.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will find a different way, using reflection looks reaaly complicated.

Comment: @Slappy it is *complicated* to just use it (like above)... to use it *efficiently* (in terms of speed and allocations) is *much more complicated than that* :)